# How to call Haskell from Javascript with GHCJS

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

I've been playing about with GHCJS. The FFI can be used to call javascript from Haskell but I can't figure out how do go the other way round. Say I had a super useful utility function I wrote in Haskell:

```
sayHello :: String -> IO ()
sayHello name = print $ "hello, " ++ name
```

Is it possible do something so I could call it from Javascript? The closest I've got is noticing that `h$main(h$main2CMainzimain)` will trigger my Haskell main function.

Comment: if [this](http://weblog.luite.com/wordpress/?p=14) still applies it will not be pretty - if you want that direction [fay](https://github.com/faylang/fay/wiki/Calling-Fay-from-JavaScript) might be a better choice

Comment: If worse comes to worse you could potentially use the FFI to solve the problem. So if you have `var haskell = {}, export = functon (name, val) { haskell[name] = val; };` and then bring `export` into Haskell via FFI, `export "sayHello" sayHello` should potentially set `haskell.sayHello` to be whatever the function is, without weird `h$main()` variables littering everything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a way to make it work. Assume we have some useful function, like

```
revString :: String -> String
revString = reverse

somethingUseful :: JSString -> IO JSString
somethingUseful = return . toJSString . revString  . fromJSString
```

In order to export that, we need to make it a callback via one of the `*Callback` functions in `GHCJS.Foreign`. But these would discard the return value, so we need a wrapper that puts the result into a second argument:

```
returnViaArgument :: (JSRef a -> IO (JSRef b)) -> JSRef a -> JSRef c -> IO ()
returnViaArgument f arg retObj = do
    r <- f arg
    setProp "ret" r retObj
```

My `main` function creates the callback, and saves it as something that’s global to JavaScript:

```
foreign import javascript unsafe "somethingUseful_ = $1"
    js_set_somethingUseful :: JSFun a -> IO ()

main = do
    callback <- syncCallback2 NeverRetain False (returnViaArgument somethingUseful)
    js_set_somethingUseful callback
```

Finally, we need a little un-wrapper on the JS side:

```
function somethingUseful (arg) {x = {}; somethingUseful_(arg, x); return x.ret};
```

and now we can use our nice Haskell-implemented function:

```
somethingUseful("Hello World!")
"!dlroW olleH"
```

I am using this trick in a real-world application. In [JsInterface.hs](https://github.com/nomeata/incredible/blob/8fa98e59a7b4414d0a78d2e327394cee9a174591/logic/js/JSInterface.hs), which is defined as `main-in` of the `executable` in the [Cabal file](https://github.com/nomeata/incredible/blob/8fa98e59a7b4414d0a78d2e327394cee9a174591/logic/incredible-logic.cabal), the `main` function sets the global java script variable `incredibleLogic_`, while the [JavaScript glue code](https://github.com/nomeata/incredible/blob/8fa98e59a7b4414d0a78d2e327394cee9a174591/logic/js/js-interface-wrapper.js) takes care of packing and unpacking the parameters.

Comment: Do you happen to have this somewhere in github? So I could compile it using GHCJS ?

Comment: Thanks, I have a look.

Comment: What is the return value here ? https://github.com/nomeata/incredible/blob/master/logic/js/js-interface-wrapper.js#L8 Where is `incredibleLogic_` coming from  here https://github.com/nomeata/incredible/blob/master/logic/js/js-interface-wrapper.js#L10 ?

Comment: Sorry for the brief comment, I was on a mobile phone. I now elaborated on it in the answer itself – does it help?

Comment: So, calling `js_set_somethingUseful`  in `main.hs` causes `somethingUseful_`  to appear in the Javascript global namespace ? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes; have a close look at the `foreign import javascript unsafe` declaration: It compiles to the JS code `"incredibleLogic_ = $1"`.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. I think I will write soon my own little example and perhaps post it here as well.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Would you be willing to include in your answer what imports did you use in Haskell? I'm trying to compile the above code and am getting 'Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘JSFun' and similar. I'll try to hunt down where the imports could be coming from, but I think it could help me and/or others if the imports were also included in the answer.

Comment: https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-base/issues/6#issuecomment-147378568 For one, `JSFun` seems to have been renamed to `Callback`

Comment: The 2015-12-18 answer works with the renamed types and functions.

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example that shows how to call a Haskell function from Javascript.  This is similar to the example provided by Joachim but compiles and runs with the latest ghcjs.

```
import GHCJS.Marshal(fromJSVal)
import GHCJS.Foreign.Callback (Callback, syncCallback1, OnBlocked(ContinueAsync))
import Data.JSString (JSString, unpack, pack)
import GHCJS.Types (JSVal)

sayHello :: String -> IO ()
sayHello name = print $ "hello, " ++ name

sayHello' :: JSVal -> IO ()
sayHello' jsval = do
    Just str <- fromJSVal jsval
    sayHello $ unpack str

foreign import javascript unsafe "js_callback_ = $1"
    set_callback :: Callback a -> IO ()

foreign import javascript unsafe "js_callback_($1)" 
    test_callback :: JSString -> IO ()

main = do
    callback <- syncCallback1 ContinueAsync sayHello'
    set_callback callback
    test_callback $ pack "world"
```

The test works by calling from Haskell into Javascript code that then calls back into Haskell.   The variable, "js_callback_", becomes available within Javascript  for use as a function that takes one string argument.

Comment: Which version of GHCJS did you use? I get these errors: `Module ‘GHCJS.Marshal’ does not export ‘fromJSVal’`, `Module ‘GHCJS.Types’ does not export ‘JSVal’` when I try to compile the above code. I'm using `ghcjs-0.2.0.20151001_ghc-7.10.2`.

Comment: dave@6d322ff6c63d:~$ ghcjs --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System for JavaScript, version 0.2.0 (GHC 7.10.3)

Comment: That is very curious. Any ideas as to what might cause us to have different modules if we both have GHCJS-0.2.0?

Comment: Not offhand.  I can look into this in more detail in a few hours.

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about your environment?  How are you invoking ghcjs?  Are you using cabal?  How did you install ghcjs?

Comment: I've used stack to install GHCJS. Here is my stack.yaml and .cabal files: https://gist.github.com/Wizek/5052b377cbc97439e523

Comment: Actually, maybe I can post to github the whole project where the compile errors are reproducible, just a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100515/discussion-between-wizek-and-dave).

Comment: The stack configuration in this github repo was configured to use ghcjs-0.2.0.20151001_ghc-7.10.2 per  the stack/ghcjs documentation : http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/ghcjs.html .   When compiling with that configuration, I also see the errors that @Wizek reports.   However, if you modify the stack.yaml file to specify ghcjs-0.2.0.20151029_ghc-7.10.2 , as described on the same documentation page, then the code compiles and runs.

Comment: How would one access `js_callback_` from a nodejs? You would have to get ghcjs to programmatically place `js_callback_` within the `module.exports` of its parent file (`all.js` I'm assuming). Is this possible?

Comment: The above example is available in github : https://github.com/dc25/ghcjsCallback .  I added a branch, nodejs, that compiles to code that runs under node.js : https://github.com/dc25/ghcjsCallback/tree/nodejs .    This branch contains a haskell -> javascript -> haskell calling sequence in which the javascript is in a javascript only source file, `Main.jsexe/tc.js`, The callback to haskell is done via the `js_callback_` variable.  It was not necessary to export `js_callback_` to access it outside of `all.js` .

Comment: In February 2024, with GHCJS 8.10.7, this example still works (almost). The only thing I had to add was `hFlush stdout` (from `System.IO`) after calling `print` to make the text appear in the browser's console.